# JavaScript Libraries in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I understand that in order to use a JavaScript library in WordPress, such as jQuery, we have to use the following code to prevent conflicts:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

But how do I go about using a library that is not in the list of defined WordPress libraries. I am in particular interested in using the library at [pikachoose.com](http://www.pikachoose.com/) which depends on jQuery, and must be intialized after jQuery. How do I go about that?

Comment: The codex is your friend: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do this:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'pikachoose',  // this is your custom name for this JS lib
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/pikachoose/jquery.pikachoose.min.js',  // this is the url address of it's file (let's say you put it in your theme directory under /js/pikachoose/ directory
        array( 'jquery' )  // it depends on jquery
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

You can find full reference of `wp_enqueue_script` here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script